# C++ Constructor initialization list with array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

What am I doing wrong here? The compiler tells me it is a syntax error.

```
class Color {
private:
    float rgba[4];
public:
    Color(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha=1.0):
            this->rgba[0] (red * alpha),
            this->rgba[1] (green*alpha)
            this->rgba[2] (blue*alpha)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: I know this is probably just a homework exercise. But check if your graphics lib really wants RGBA pre-multiplied by A

Comment: Is it a bad idea to multiply by A? Could you please tell me more about it?

Comment: The reason for the "A" is to change the all the colors at once, to handle overlaying images etc. Normally the graphics hardware would do the multiplication at display time.

Comment: `this->rgba[0]` is an error. The only thing that can appear after `:` is a member identifier, i.e. `rgba` is the only option for this class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
Color(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha=1.0):
            rgba{red * alpha, green*alpha, blue*alpha, 0}
    {

    }
```

Comment: This assumes a C++11 compliant compiler. Some people still aren't using C++11.

Comment: Some people haven't discovered computers yet so we should print this answer out and do a leaflet drop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asigment operator instead of parentetheses:

```
this->rgba[0](red * alpha) // wrong
this->rgba[1] = red * alpha // ok
```